# How to put unfinished education on a resume

Tags: resume, education

What is the best way to put on your resume you attended some college, but do not have a degree?

Comment: Are you currently a student, or did you leave college entirely?

Comment: This could vary on several factors. Are you currently attending that college? Do you have any plans to complete your degree?

Comment: Related - http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/13311/should-i-put-my-2nd-undergraduate-studies-that-i-did-not-finish-on-my-resume

Answer (score 0):

You almost need to just to explain gaps in employment

Attended College X from date start - date end
If you had a declared major and were accepted into that major then state it
If you say *attended* rather BS or BA ... it is clear you did not graduate

If you were just going part time and did not really get far enough to take any advanced courses then maybe leave it off

If you dropped a PhD for a Masters then just list the Masters.  If you got 1/2 way through a 4 year degree and settled for a junior college then just list the junior college.  If you you took algebra and English dropped out and got Ds then don't list it.  Ask yourself if you would like to produce the transcript if asked.

Comment: I disagree with the leaving it off. If you attended any College I think that it would be best to put it down within, let's say 2 years. To me it shows that you have ambition. I feel differently about a man who went to College part time and had to quit due to time constraints/other responsibilities, than a man who worked the same job and seemingly didn't try to improve his situation.

Comment: @zfrisch Any college?  6 credits into a 2 or 4 year degree does not show ambition.   Quit due to time constraints - I would think this is someone that is not good at managing time.  Other responsibilities - OP gave no indication of extenuating circumstances.  I just answered the question as I read it.

Comment: Still, I think it's applicable. It's my opinion and it may be biased based on my experience with the education system, but yes, I think it's valid. I had to work full time while attending full time school and didn't qualify for financial aid until years after my friends had already graduated. There are a billion reasons why school doesn't work out, but if you at least attempt I'll give someone the benefit of the doubt. I guess it really depends on who's reading your resume.

Comment: @zfrisch Cool.  I guess I would not just list two classes unless I had a good reason why I only finished two classes.